# Three.JS, How to configure the camera to do not upside down the model?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, interactive, collada

I am working on a 3D model of a building using Three.JS and Collada loader.

I'm improving my system interactivity, but I have two main issues:

1- When I rotate the model in the scene, it rotates in 3 axis and it makes it upside down! I want to keep the model fixed in horizontal axis and only rotate it along Y axis (Up).

[A live sample](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44791710/rotate/Model.html) How I can rotate this cube only around Y Axis (Up)?

2-How I can have a smooth control on the system using mouse movements? For example in big models, it is not easy to zoom to a specific small object smoothly. How I can configure the camera to zoom, pan and rotate smoothly?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I am beginner to 3JS. I wanted to know how did you create 3D model of a building?

Comment: I used Autodesk Revit to create an IFC file. Then I exported IFC file to Collada using Blender. There is a Blender plug in which reads IFC and you can easily export that to Collada. You can also use Sketch up to create Collada files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not rotating the model. You are rotating the camera.

Use `OrbitControls` instead of `TrackballControls` -- it will keep the camera right-side-up.

`OrbitControls` should be smooth. If it is not, then there may be something wrong with your model. That can only be handled on a case-by-case basis.

You are using a version of the library that is a year old. It is wise to update to the current version.

three.js r.57.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in your script:

```
controls.getMouseProjectionOnBall2 = controls.getMouseProjectionOnBall;
controls.getMouseProjectionOnBall = function(x, y){
    return controls.getMouseProjectionOnBall2.call(controls, x, controls.screen.height/2);
}
```

Regarding the jerky movements, I see you're doing everything possible already (often people omit requestAnimationFrame). I don't think there's anything you can do to reduce jerkiness other than reduce the complexity of your building.